# SSIS Import Naming

Tags: ssis

I am building an SSIS package to grab a daily snapshot of order data. This data comes from DB2 and the column names are essentially meaningless. I'm fairly new to SSIS and was wondering if there is an accepted practice on renaming columns on import vs. aliasing them later in a view. Or does it matter?

My conservative brain says to just get the data and deal with the labels later but I know the good engineers at Microsoft built those features for a reason. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For sake of debugging / analysing I prefer to rename the columns as soon as possible - that is either directly in the data flow source (if using a query) or via "derived columns" - and insert them into corresponding colums in the destination table. The last thing you want - if it comes to tracking down fault data - is to check the aliases within a view everytime.